# Renaming group of related variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Note: I'm not sure what is a good title for this question. I will be happy to fix it.

Suppose I have this test dataframe:

```
library(tidyverse)
test.dat <- tibble(
  "User1" = c("Aaron","Aaron","Charlie"),
  "User2" = c("Ben","Ben","Aaron"),
  "User3" = c("Charlie","Charlie","Ben"),
  "first_1" = c("A","A","C"),
  "first_2" = c("B","B","A"),
  "first_3" = c("C","C","B"),
  "second_1" = c("A","A","C"),
  "second_2" = c("B","B","A"),
  "second_3" = c("C","C","B"),
  "third_1" = c("A","A","C"),
  "third_2" = c("B","B","A"),
  "third_3" = c("C","C","B")
)

# A tibble: 3 x 12
  User1   User2 User3   first_1 first_2 first_3 second_1 second_2 second_3 third_1 third_2 third_3
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 Aaron   Ben   Charlie A       B       C       A        B        C        A       B       C      
2 Aaron   Ben   Charlie A       B       C       A        B        C        A       B       C      
3 Charlie Aaron Ben     C       A       B       C        A        B        C       A       B
```

I want User1 and variables with `_1` to be always referring to Aaron, User2 to be always Ben and variables with `_2` and so on.

What I can do is to locate where each name is in User1:User3 by making temporary variable `Loc`, then use `case_when`:

```
test.try <- test.dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(U1Loc = case_when(User1 == "Aaron" ~ 1,
                           User2 == "Aaron" ~ 2,
                           User3 == "Aaron" ~ 3),
         U2Loc = case_when(User1 == "Ben" ~ 1,
                           User2 == "Ben" ~ 2,
                           User3 == "Ben" ~ 3),
         U3Loc = case_when(User1 == "Charlie" ~ 1,
                           User2 == "Charlie" ~ 2,
                           User3 == "Charlie" ~ 3)) %>%
  mutate(newUser_1 = case_when(U1Loc == 1 ~ User1,
                                U1Loc == 2 ~ User2,
                                U1Loc == 3 ~ User3),
         newUser_2 = case_when(U2Loc == 1 ~ User1,
                                U2Loc == 2 ~ User2,
                                U2Loc == 3 ~ User3),
         newUser_3 = case_when(U3Loc == 1 ~ User1,
                                U3Loc == 2 ~ User2,
                                U3Loc == 3 ~ User3)) %>%
  mutate(newFirst_1 = case_when(U1Loc == 1 ~ first_1,
                                U1Loc == 2 ~ first_2,
                                U1Loc == 3 ~ first_3),
         newFirst_2 = case_when(U2Loc == 1 ~ first_1,
                                U2Loc == 2 ~ first_2,
                                U2Loc == 3 ~ first_3),
         newFirst_3 = case_when(U3Loc == 1 ~ first_1,
                                U3Loc == 2 ~ first_2,
                                U3Loc == 3 ~ first_3)) %>%
  mutate(newSecond_1 = case_when(U1Loc == 1 ~ second_1,
                                 U1Loc == 2 ~ second_2,
                                 U1Loc == 3 ~ second_3),
         newSecond_2 = case_when(U2Loc == 1 ~ second_1,
                                 U2Loc == 2 ~ second_2,
                                 U2Loc == 3 ~ second_3),
         newSecond_3 = case_when(U3Loc == 1 ~ second_1,
                                 U3Loc == 2 ~ second_2,
                                 U3Loc == 3 ~ second_3)) %>%
  select(starts_with("new"))
```

to get

```
> test.try
# A tibble: 3 x 9
# Rowwise: 
  newUser_1 newUser_2 newUser_3 newFirst_1 newFirst_2 newFirst_3 newSecond_1 newSecond_2 newSecond_3
  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
1 Aaron     Ben       Charlie   A          B          C          A           B           C          
2 Aaron     Ben       Charlie   A          B          C          A           B           C          
3 Aaron     Ben       Charlie   A          B          C          A           B           C
```

However, the more variables there are, the more cumbersome this becomes.  Is there a way to achieve this other than for loop, preferably in the tidy method?  My guess is to use `across()` but I can't seem to get it to work as I imagine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could do this easily with pivoting to 'long' format and then do the reshape back to wide after replacing the values

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- test.dat %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c('.value', 'grp'),
         names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])_?(?=[0-9])") %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    mutate(across(User:third, first)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = c(User, first, second, third)) %>%
    select(-rn)
```

-output

```
out
# A tibble: 3 x 12
#  User_1 User_2 User_3  first_1 first_2 first_3 second_1 second_2 second_3 third_1 third_2 third_3
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Aaron  Ben    Charlie A       B       C       A        B        C        A       B       C      
#2 Aaron  Ben    Charlie A       B       C       A        B        C        A       B       C      
#3 Aaron  Ben    Charlie A       B       C       A        B        C        A       B       C
```

---

If we want to rename the columns with `new` as prefix

```
library(stringr)
out %>%
    rename_all(~ str_c('new', .))
```

---

Or another option is to create a keyvalue dataset to match and replace if the values in the columns are not in an order

```
keydat <- tibble(grp = as.character(1:3), UserKey = c("Aaron", "Ben", "Charlie"),
      abbr = substr(UserKey, 1, 1))


test.dat %>% 
        mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
        pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c('.value', 'grp'),
             names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])_?(?=[0-9])") %>%
        left_join(keydat) %>% 
        mutate(User = UserKey) %>% 
        mutate(across(first:third, ~ abbr)) %>%
        select(-UserKey, -abbr) %>% 
        pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = c(User, first, second, third)) %>%
        select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 12
#  User_1 User_2 User_3  first_1 first_2 first_3 second_1 second_2 second_3 third_1 third_2 third_3
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 Aaron  Ben    Charlie A       B       C       A        B        C        A       B       C      
#2 Aaron  Ben    Charlie A       B       C       A        B        C        A       B       C      
#3 Aaron  Ben    Charlie A       B       C       A        B        C        A       B       C
```

Comment: In the first approach: `mutate(across(User:third, first)) ` result in error, since across() expects function for second argument.  I assumed you meant `mutate(across(User:third, ~ first))`, but it doesn't return the expected output.  Would you kindly take a look?

*Edit*: Nevermind, specifying dplyr like `mutate(across(User:third, dplyr::first))` resulted in the expected outcome. I'm not sure whatelse R thought it was, since I didn't load any other packages.

Comment: @aiorr I am not sure why it had an issue.  The `first` is also from `data.table`. May be you also have a column name 'first'?

Comment: Most likely, since the `pivot_longer()` in the previous step would've transformed first_1,2,3 into a single column called `first`.

Comment: Probably, my version of dplyr didn't pick up that